# ERROR 000224 when running an ArcPy script for map automation

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I am using ArcMap 10.7 and PyCharm (I am new with the latter). I began to run a script that was passed on to me to automate maps. Strangely enough, it first ran alright... but then (and I am not sure if I accidentally did something), it completely crashed. I believe it is an appending issue but I am not quite sure. Anyway, when I first run it with the following code:

```
print ("ABTMapNewstart_" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
if arcpy.Exists(MapSelect_shpInterim):
    arcdel(MapSelect_shpInterim)
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(MapSelect_shp)
arcpy.Select_analysis(County, MapSelect_shpInterim, qry2)
arcpy.Append_management(MapSelect_shpInterim, MapSelect_shp, "NO_TEST", "", "")
counties = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdabt, "Counties", df)[0]
selectedMun = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdabt, 'munsumrd', df)[0]
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(selectedMun, "NEW_SELECTION", qry1)
mxdabt.dataDrivenPages.refresh()
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", qry2)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties, "CLEAR_SELECTION", "")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxdabt, r"V:\\Maps\\" + a[1].replace(" ", "_") + "_" + a[
    0].replace(" ", "_") + "_" + mapName + "_Map.pdf")
```

I get the following error.

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:.py", line 184, in <module>
    arcpy.Append_management(MapSelect_shpInterim, MapSelect_shp, "NO_TEST", "", "")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4256, in Append
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000224: Cannot insert features
Failed to execute (Append).
```

Please ignore the outpaths in the two codes, I blocked them out for privacy. Anyway...interestingly enough, when I hash out the `arcpy.Append_management(MapSelect_shpInterim, MapSelect_shp, "NO_TEST", "", "")` line, it runs fine, with the maps showing up as they should be and where they should be. But it gets stranger... I then tried to fix the indentation, by doing this:

```
print ("ABTMapNewstart_" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
if arcpy.Exists(MapSelect_shpInterim):
    arcdel(MapSelect_shpInterim)
    arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(MapSelect_shp)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(County, MapSelect_shpInterim, qry2)
    arcpy.Append_management(MapSelect_shpInterim, MapSelect_shp, "NO_TEST", "", "")
    counties = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdabt, "Counties", df)[0]
    selectedMun = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdabt, 'munsumrd', df)[0]
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(selectedMun, "NEW_SELECTION", qry1)
    mxdabt.dataDrivenPages.refresh()
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", qry2)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties, "CLEAR_SELECTION", "")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxdabt,
                              r"V:\EHAP\Maps" + a[1].replace(" ", "_") + "_" + a[
                                  0].replace(" ",
                                             "_") + "_" + mapName + "_Map.pdf")
```

and the code runs without errors... but the map files are not produced! I have no idea regarding how to solve this and what I am doing wrong. Would anyone be able to provide some insight?

Comment: Have you tried running that Append using the 'Append' tool in ArcMap with settings that match the arguments in the script?  Do you get any error there?

Comment: good question...I didn't yet but I will give it a shot.